# Azure AD B2C Home Realm Discovery customer self service

Tags: azure, single-sign-on, azure-ad-b2c

I am looking into using Azure AD B2C to support external identity providers. It looks pretty simple to set up HRD and have the domain route to the correct provider (https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/home-realm-discovery-modern).

I'm getting confused if there is something within B2C or even within Azure that will support customers registering their own IDPs to our B2C tenant? Or it it's something I need to build myself. I may have 100s if not 1000s of customers using their own providers so I want to avoid manually upserting them.

I saw some companies had apps in the Azure App Gallery (ex: Dropbox, Salesforce, etc) that handled setting up SSO and registering an identity provider.

Answer (score 0):

The Apps gallery is for Azure AD, not B2C.

You would have to do something yourself.

Given that it's just an XML file, you could have a config. file that contains the parameters and then write code that adds the technical profiles, adds the domain to the list as per the sample etc.

It would take into account that some are OIDC and some are SAML.

You would also have to add the client secrets etc.

This [script](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/Scripts/tree/master/IEFTenantSetupV2) from @JasSuri shows an example of how to do that.

Comment: Thanks. 

My understanding of Apps Gallery was a little different, let me know if I am way off:

If I downloaded the Dropbox one I can use my AD tenant to SSO with Dropbox. Then if I created my own App for my SP,  customers could use it to have SSO with thier AD tenants. And my SP behind the scenes would be using B2C to manage all the AD tenants signing up.

Comment: Bit lost. Maybe expand your question with more detail and a diagram.

Comment: Hopefully this diagram better explains. Two customers both setup the Dropbox Gallery App in Azure to use their AD for SSO with Dropbox. Now when that user, bob, goes to login with bob@foo.com how does Dropbox know to use Customer 1's foo.com Azure AD for SSO? https://lucid.app/lucidchart/feafec98-3246-4911-b16d-b60b9b7318f9/edit?invitationId=inv_aef60361-cde8-4b2e-80af-53bab4bf533a

Comment: Oh ... I might get it? In this case Dropbox isn't doing HRD. On the Dropbox login page they will click login with Microsoft/Office 365. Then Dropbox will route to a generic microsoft auth page. The user will enter their microsoft credentials and it will authenticate successfully if they have setup the Dropbox gallery app.

Comment: Yup. That's correct.